# Is there a Google Apps Admin API for configuring the URL Blacklist and URL Blacklist Exception?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I would like to configure the URL Blacklist and URL Blacklist Exception settings for an Organization in my Google Apps domain via an API.  Is this possible?  I don't see anything obvious at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/ but my understanding is that some companies like Promevo have written products that do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, you're referring to the Chrome blacklist settings, correct?

If so, there's no API to modify these settings. With Promevo and others, I believe they've actually written extensions which report back to some type of management environment outside of the Google Apps Admin console. Via these consoles, they're able enforce other policies on the devices.

A popular example of this in EDU is Guardian EDU (goguardian.com).

Comment: I submitted https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3573 to get clarification on future plans to support this.